# Understanding structs containing structs and how to initialize them properly

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm trying to understand how to properly initialize structs which contain other structs (especially arrays of structs!). I made this little overview representing my current understanding and wanted to ask whether this is the right or wrong way to do:

(Note that for the sake of brevity destroy methods and checks of malloc() are omitted.)

The simplest struct contains static variables only:

```
typedef struct simple {
    int variable;
} Simple;

Simple *create_simple(int value) {
    Simple *simple = malloc(sizeof(Simple));
    simple->variable = value;
    return simple;
}
```

Using dynamic variables like arrays require additional allocation:

```
typedef struct array {
    size_t length;
    int *element;
} Array;

Array *create_array(size_t length) {
    Array *array = malloc(sizeof(Array));
    array->length = length;
    array->element = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    return array;
}
```

Same goes for structs containing pointers to other structs. In this case we need to allocate the memory for the internal struct seperately:

```
typedef struct container {
    Simple *internal;
} Container;

Container *create_container(int value) {
    Container *container = malloc(sizeof(Container));
    // Is this correct? Or should I just malloc(sizeof(Simple))?
    container->internal = create_simple(value);
    return container;
}
```

More complex is a struct containing a dynamic array of struct pointers:

```
typedef struct struct_array {
    size_t length;
    Simple **element;
} StructArray;

StructArray *create_struct_array(size_t length) {
    StructArray *structArray = malloc(sizeof(Array));
    structArray->length = length;
    // Would I alternatively need to loop over 
    // the array and call create_simple() on each index?
    structArray->element = malloc(length * sizeof(Simple));
    return structArray;
}
```

Now there can be any nesting depth of structs:

```
typedef struct complex_container {
    size_t length;
    StructArray *element;
} ComplexContainer;

ComplexContainer *create_complex_container(size_t length) {
    ComplexContainer *complexContainer = malloc(sizeof(ComplexContainer));
    complexContainer->length = length;
    // Is this valid? My create_struct_array function should 
    // allocate the memory?
    complexContainer->element = create_struct_array(length);
    return complexContainer;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think this is incorrect?

Comment: Mostly the question whether to use my create functions inside of other create functions OR malloc inside them.

Comment: And if it would not be better to use arrays inside of struct definitions instead of pointers only

Comment: The common idiom is to use sizeof object instead of sizeof(type of object). It's safer in the long run, in case the object changes types. So write "foo *p = malloc(sizeof *p);" instead.

Your variable names are way too long and makes lines longer than they have to be. That's not much of a problem in the snippets above, but would reduce code quality when error handling and more struct members are added.